# Flutter JobIntentService in androidx.core.app has been deprecated

Tags: flutter, dart

JobIntentService in androidx.core.app has been deprecated when i run the code
[Error Pict](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asQtz.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.